# How can I prevent a TTY (e.g. /dev/tty1) from writing to the framebuffer (/dev/fb0)?

Tags: tty, framebuffer

I'm running a Raspbian Buster server with no Xserver.  I want to display wallpaper on a connected television but /dev/tty1 keeps over writing /dev/fb0 either with a blinking cursor or just refreshing randomly 60 seconds later after I make the cursor invisible (from getty@tty1.service).  My new strategy is to completely prevent /dev/tty1 from ever writing to the framebuffer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just use a X server or Wayland server? Which will handle tty problem for you

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid the overhead and I'm testing writing images to the framebuffer directly.

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer, but I still know another alternative of using DRM. https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs I used this code once. It wasn't interrupted by tty.

Comment: Can you do something like this maybe: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Run_software_on_tty1_console_instead_of_login_getty.html

Comment: I wonder why you just don't vt-switch: `openvt -s your-fb-app`. Does that device not support it?

Comment: @RafaelKitover that doesn't help because I'm running the wallpaper as a timed systemd service, not a scripts from a console.

Comment: @mosvy because everything is automated via systemd.  I'm not using consoles at all.

Comment: There would be no `/dev/tty1` if your system weren't using consoles at all (like eg. my android phone). So your system is obviously using "consoles". `openvt -s` should find the 1st free console and run a program in it. `chvt n` where `n` is a console not managed by systemd/sysvinit would prevent mgetty/whatever from writing its prompt to it.

Comment: @mosvy interesting.  I think I will test your idea soon.  But I have solved my problem I think by disabling the getty@tty1.service and then making tty1 cursor invisible.  It seems to be working.

Comment: The problem with disabling that getty@tty1.service and no cross-over serial cable around is that you may not be able to access your device if ssh or anything else goes wrong.

Comment: @mosvy that is a good point.  I'll have to resolve that or find another solution.

Comment: If something goes wrong you can always boot recovery mode from grub and get an emergency shell.

Comment: @RafaelKitover Interesting.  Can I be sure the emergency shell won't be trying to use TTY1?

Comment: I don't know to be honest but I doubt it, the recovery shell is different from normal consoles.

Comment: @mosvy instead of disabling getty@tty1.service I'm just going to `systemctl stop getty@tty1.service` so I can still access /dev/tty1 after a reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop /dev/tty1 from overwriting the buffer I'm using

`systemctl stop getty@tty1.service` and then make the cursor invisible with..

`/usr/bin/tput civis > /dev/tty1`

This allows me access to console after reboot should I lose access via ssh.